# Regex: Add html link to another html link in the same html tag (Double the html Link)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this html class with a html links inside. The problem is not clickable on mouse over. So, I want to make it clickable.

`<p class="mb-40px"><strong>* Surs&#259;:</strong> https://www.larte.es/2021/03/01/abierta.html </p>`

**Must become:**

`<p class="mb-40px"><strong>* Surs&#259;:</strong> <a href=https://www.larte.es/2021/03/01/abierta.html class="color-dada" target="_new">https://www.larte.es/2021/03/01/abierta.html</a> </p>`

so, in fact, I must double the link, put in front `<a href=` and `class="color-dada" target="_new">` and close with `</a>`

Answer (score 1):

**FIND:**

`(<p class="mb-40px"><strong>\* Surs&#259;:</strong>) .*?(https.*?html) (</p>)`

**REPLACE BY:**

`\1 <a href=\2 class="color-dada" target="_new">\2</a> \3`